# Hibernate, trouble merging

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I'm trying to updating an object in my database, from my servlet. However it successfully runs without any errors, but does not delete.

my HibernateUtil looks like:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static final String HIBER = "hibernate.cfg.xml";

    public HibernateUtil() {
        try {
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().addResource(HIBER).configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void closeSessionFactory() {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

and I instantiate above class when servlet init.

```
@Override
    public void init() {

        hiber = new HibernateUtil();
        System.out.println("Servlet Initialized");
    }
```

I used openSession before, and read that it was better to use getCurrentSession for web applications, and now I'm trying to do it over.

```
String add = request.getParameter("houseId");
            hiber.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction tx = session1.beginTransaction();

            House house = (House) session1.get(House.class, Long.parseLong(add));

            System.out.println(house.getAddress());

            SessionUser.getHouses().add(house);

            session1.merge(SessionUser);        
            tx.commit();
            session1.close();

            System.out.println(house.getAddress());
```

I edited my trouble code with smth more simple. I just got no idea why this aren't working.

Comment: if you forget to commit the transaction and close the session. it won't able to commit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please commit the transaction and close the session.

```
  String add = request.getParameter("Id");
        Session session1 = hiber.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();   
        Transaction tx; 
        try {
            tx = session1.beginTransaction();
            for (Iterator<House> iterator = SessionUser.gethouse().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                House house = iterator.next();
                if (house.getProjectId() == Long.parseLong(add)) {
                    iterator.remove();
                    session1.remove(house);
                    session1.flush();
                }
            }

            session1.merge(SessionUser);
            tx.commit();    

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {         
            System.out.println("______");
            session1.close();
        }
```

Comment: I am hoping.. SessionUser Entity has many House Entity. And, you do have cascade effect define over the OneToMany relationship in SessionUser entity.  "@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="user")
    public List<House> house;

Comment: yes I do. I made it work at one point, but with a different method. But can't really see why I cannot make this one work aswell.

Comment: I think orphan-removal part is missing.. @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true). Or, we can manually delete the child by using session1.remove(house). I have edited the code for the same.